# Install grafana without elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch, opentsdb, grafana

I’m trying to install grafana to work with OpenTSDB datasource. I’d like to know, what should I do to install it without elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using grafana with Influxdb and I'm not using elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

[Grafana 2](http://grafana.org/blog/2015/03/30/Grafana-2-Beta1.html) is out in beta and I've been using that in production for a while. Grafana 2 now has its own data store, which either uses MySQL or SQLite. But you can always use Elasticsearch as well. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.grafana.org/v2.0/installation/configuration/#database)

**Update:** Stable version of Grafana 2 is now out, and it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana is a frontend, you will need some kind of database to store values and configuration in. I just grabbed the .tar.gz file from grafana's downloads page, created a config.js and pointed it at my influxdb server. No elasticsearch here, either.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [gofana](https://github.com/jwilder/gofana) which will allow you to run Grafana without Elasticsearch.  It's a self-contained binary that allows you to store dashboards on the filesystem and not in Elasticsearch or InfluxDB.  It also supports HTTPS and basic authentication.

Note: I'm the author of gofana.