# How to mimic a grafana backend?

Tags: elasticsearch, influxdb, grafana

My application producers counters. I'd like to use grafana to view them. It seems `grafana` depends on `influxDB` or `elasticsearch`.

Is there a way to make `grafana` read data from my own app so I don't need to store them in another backend?

Comment: This is an almost word-by-word duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26913267/2413043

Answer (score 0):

You can include an [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net) datasource in between your App and Grafana.

Like this:

```
datasources: {
    'OpenTSDB-TEST': {
        default: true,
        type: 'opentsdb',
        url: "http://my_opentsdb_server:4242"
    }
}
```

See more OpenTSDB configuration details [here](http://grafana.org/docs/features/opentsdb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: https://github.com/grafana/datasource-plugin-genericdatasource

To configure it with version 2.6 do the following:
Put the plugin's files to folder, let's say, "genericdatasource".
Then copy this folder to /public/app/plugins/datasource/. 
In `directives.js` change `templateUrl` of `query.editor.html` to:

```
'public/app/plugins/datasource/genericdatasource/partials/query.editor.html'
```

also change `templateUrl` of `query.options.html` to:

```
'public/app/plugins/datasource/genericdatasource/partials/query.options.html'
```

In `plugin.json` change `module` to:

```
'app/plugins/datasource/genericdatasource/datasource',
```

and change `config` to:

```
'public/app/plugins/datasource/genericdatasource/partials/config.html'
```

Then restart grafana-server. The new data source should now be avalilable in the data source type dropdown in the Add Data Source View.

Use option "proxy" there (not "direct") to work correctly with cross-domain requests.

You just need to implement 3 methods in your backend: /,search, query.

Look at examples here:

```
https://gist.github.com/bergquist/bc4aa5baface3cffa109
https://gist.github.com/tral/1fe649455fe2de9fb8fe
```